# Excel range of non-consecutive rows to clipboard

Tags: c#, excel, object, range, clipboard

I have a FindRange that finds rows with the text `€´(lblValutaTeken.Text) in my Excel sheet.

What I need to do is get the rows(multiple!) that contain the text and copy them to clipboard. My range is not consecutive rows, which is the basis of my despair.

So far I got this

```
            object[,] cellValues = null;

        try
        {
            Excel.Range currentFind = null;
            Excel.Range firstFind = null;

            var missing = Missing.Value;

            Excel.Range RangeWithValutaSigns = xlApp.ActiveSheet.Range("g1", "g500");

            currentFind = RangeWithValutaSigns.Find(lblValutaTeken.Text, missing,
                Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false,
                missing, missing);

            while (currentFind != null)
            {
                if (firstFind == null)
                {
                    firstFind = currentFind;
                }
                else if (currentFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1)
                      == firstFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
                {
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("~~~~ currentFind.Row = " + currentFind.Row);

                Excel.Range currentFindRow = currentFind.Range[("B" + currentFind.Row), ("H" + currentFind.Row)];

                cellValues = (object[,])currentFindRow.Value2;
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(cellValues))
                {
                    string name = descriptor.Name;
                    object value = descriptor.GetValue(cellValues);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", name, value);
                }
                for (int j = 1; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(cellValues[i, j].ToString());
                }
                i = i + 1;


                currentFind = RangeWithValutaSigns.FindNext(currentFind);


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Er is een fout gemaakt tijdens het kopiëren van de productregels uit de offerte naar het clipboard." + System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine + "Controleer of er een excel geopend is met daarin regels met productcodes uit de LookApp." + System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine + "Error message:" + System.Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
        }

        Clipboard.SetDataObject(cellValues);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with putting answers from multiple other Q&A's together I came up with this. Not very elegant, but it does precisely what I wanted it to.

Step 1. Create a datatable

Step 2. Use Excel.Range.Find to find the ranges(=cells) that have my valutasign (is same as lblvalutasign.txt, for instance € or $ or CAD)

Step 3. Each time a range is found I use Range.Offset to put cellvalues into my datable in the corresponding column.

Step 4. Put the whole datatable into a datagridview. This can be a non-visible datagridview if you want. Lay-out the datagridview the way you want to.

Step 5. DataGridView.SelectAll() and copy to clipboard with

```
DataObject d = dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent();
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(d);
```

Step 6. Use ctr+v to paste anywhere!

```
        Excel.Application xlApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

        Excel.Range myRange;
        myRange = xlApp.ActiveSheet.UsedRange;

        DataTable dtProductRowsFromExcel = new DataTable(); //to save all productrows form excel offer.


        dtProductRowsFromExcel.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(String)); //column 1          Excel B
        dtProductRowsFromExcel.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(String)); //column 2        Excel C
        dtProductRowsFromExcel.Columns.Add("Unit", typeof(String)); //column 3          Excel D
        dtProductRowsFromExcel.Columns.Add("ValutaUnit", typeof(String)); //column 4    Excel E
        dtProductRowsFromExcel.Columns.Add("PriceUnit", typeof(String)); //column 5     Excel F
        dtProductRowsFromExcel.Columns.Add("ValutaTotal", typeof(String)); //column 6   Excel G
        dtProductRowsFromExcel.Columns.Add("PriceTotal", typeof(String)); //column 7    Excel H


        try
        {
            Excel.Range currentFind = null;
            Excel.Range firstFind = null;

            var missing = Missing.Value;


            Excel.Range RangeWithValutaSigns = xlApp.ActiveSheet.Range("g1", "g500");
            currentFind = RangeWithValutaSigns.Find(lblValutaTeken.Text, missing,
                Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false,
                missing, missing);

            while (currentFind != null)
            {

                if (firstFind == null)
                {
                    firstFind = currentFind;
                }
                else if (currentFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1)
                      == firstFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
                {
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("~~~~ currentFind.Row = " + currentFind.Row);

                string B = currentFind.Offset[0, -5].Value2.ToString();
                string C = (currentFind.Offset[0, -4].Value2 != null) ? currentFind.Offset[0, -4].Value2.ToString() : "";
                string D = (currentFind.Offset[0, -3].Value2 != null) ? currentFind.Offset[0, -3].Value2.ToString() : "";
                string E = (currentFind.Offset[0, -2].Value2 != null) ? currentFind.Offset[0, -2].Value2.ToString() : "";
                string F = (currentFind.Offset[0, -1].Value2 != null) ? currentFind.Offset[0, -1].Value2.ToString() : "";
                string G = currentFind.Value2.ToString();
                string H = (currentFind.Offset[0, 1].Value2 != null) ? currentFind.Offset[0, 1].Value2.ToString() : "";

                dtProductRowsFromExcel.Rows.Add(B, C, D, E, F, G, H);

                currentFind = RangeWithValutaSigns.FindNext(currentFind);

                }

            // to check datatable in output window use:
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dtProductRowsFromExcel.Rows)
            {
                foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }

            }

            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtProductRowsFromExcel;
            dataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText;
            dataGridView1.SelectAll();


            DataObject d = dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent();
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(d);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error message:" + System.Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you or not, but here is my idea:
If you are searching for rows with some text criteria, why not create a string array with that criteria, and then filter your excel file based on your criteria, afterwards, copying those rows.

Example :

```
string[] Criteria = new string[1]
Criteria[0] = "Your Criteria"; (if the criteria can vary you can use * )
Criteria[1] = "Some other Criteria";
```

And then filter your excel sheet based on a criteria:
Create a range:

```
Xl.Range myRange = yourSheet.UsedRange;
```

next filter :

```
myRange.AutoFilter(7, Criteria[0], xl.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlOr, Criteria[1], true);
            xl.Range my_Range= myRange.SpecialCells(xl.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);
```

And now all you need to do is select and copy your remaining  **visible** rows and paste them.

Hopefully this will be of some help.

Comment: thanks, this is indeed an interesting way to go about it! I have tried it and it works smoothly. I am currently investigating another method of holding the foundrange in a datatable. This seems nice to have because one can use it to populate a datagridview or copy to clipboard etc... I'll try to come back to post my solution!

Comment: If you are trying to take some info from excel and throw it in a datagridview, let me know, as I too have had something of the sorts recently and I can perhaps help you somehow.
In my case I format an excel file and upload the result into the application, in the datagridview.

Comment: I would prefer to keep the excel exactly the same, for future use, actually. I have fouond Range.Find and am now adding cells by offset of the foundrange into a datatable. I'll post my answer!